Area2D embedded in UI does not receive mouse events
I am using a hierarchy of Control nodes (in a CanvasLayer as was suggested in another question) to display a user interface.
At one place in that user interface, I want to display a small 2D game world with various Node2D instances (an interactive editor to configure the player). There are certain arbitrarily shaped hotspots on that 2D player that users should be able to click (and then edit by choosing options in the UI). I have modelled the hotspots like this:
(A) Area2D
  (B) CollisionShape2D
    (C) Sprite2D

On (A), I have registered handles for the mouse_entered and mouse_exited events. input_pickable is set to true for (A), and collision layer 1 is active.
Unfortunately, the mouse events are not fired.

I have so far tried two ways of embedding the 2D world inside the UI:
"Directly":
(H) <some UI controls>
  (I) PanelContainer
    (J) Control
      (M) Node2D

(J) just serves for centering (M) inside the available area.
With a sub-viewport:
(H) <some UI controls>
  (I) PanelContainer
    (K) SubViewportContainer
      (L) SubViewport
        (M) Node2D

In there, (L) has handle_input_locally set to true (but setting it to false makes no difference). Also, gui_disable_input is false.
In both cases, (M) is actually a scene with a Node2D(-derived object) at its root, which contains a hierarchy of visible and invisible 2D nodes. The visible nodes all render correctly in both cases.
How can I make the mouse interaction work here?

In addition to your answer, I want to point out that a similar matter involves your "direct" approach. Since the Area2D is nested in a Control Nodes hierarchy, it will receive the mouse input only after it travels across its ancestors (this is only about propagation, not execution). However, Controls may prevent it from propagating downwards in the Scene Tree and reaching the Area2D. All you need to do is make sure that the mouse_filter property of every ancestor of Area2D is not set to "Stop":

Instead, choose either "Pass" or "Ignore" depending on whether the current Control needs to respond to user input too.

In the "direct" approach, they're all set to pass, and yet, no input events arrive at the Area2D.

@O.R.Mapper It has to be "Ignore". "Pass" does not mean click through, it means bubble up.

I am using the second approach with the sub-viewport:
(H) <some UI controls>
  (I) PanelContainer
    (K) SubViewportContainer
      (L) SubViewport
        (M) Node2D

In (L), I have to set physics_object_picking to true, then mouse events arrive at my Area2D instances.
